# HOW TO USE the Script-Migration file generated from visual studio for production on an Ubuntu PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I write Script-Migration on Visual Studio console, It creates a file called uhftsodk.sql that contains something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "__EFMigrationsHistory" (
    "MigrationId" character varying(150) NOT NULL,
    "ProductVersion" character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK___EFMigrationsHistory" PRIMARY KEY ("MigrationId")
);
```

I am a Windows user, but the production environment I am trying to implement is an Ubuntu 20.04 vm, with PostgreSQL.
I run this script in PostgreSQL from Ubuntu and it generated the table called "__EFMigrationsHistory"
But, What else am I supposed to do from there?
I want to create all my tables I used in Visual Studio for this particular project.  I am using PostgreSQL for both scenarios, and it is working on development (using add-migration name and update-database) but not working in production...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the CLI commands [dotnet ef migrations script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-database-update) and [dotnet ef database update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-database-update).

CLI commands can be run in any environment (Windows and Linux). You would generally script the migrations first, then review the script, then test the script, then backup the production database and then apply the script to the production database.

If this does not answer your question, please go into more details, where the problem for you lies. (The question has been asked a bit vague.)

Comment: Thanks for your time lauxjpn. I appreciated it.

Comment: @dangelogonzalez No problem. I'm glad you figured out what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I deleted the migrations, so when I run Script-Migration from Package Manager Console, it did not create all the tables, just the __EFMigrationsHistory table...

So, I created a new migration again, and then run Script-migration. Now the file was completed.